# malloc(sizeof(char))→10000要素の配列を作れてしまうのはなぜですか？

Tags: c

環境　ubuntu
clionにてrun

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    char *old_string,*new_string;
    old_string=malloc(sizeof(char));
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
        old_string[i]=i%10;

        //new_string=realloc(old_string,i+2);
        //old_string=new_string;
        printf("インデックス：%d 中身：%d\n",i,old_string[i]);
    }
    free(old_string);

    return 0;
}
```

結果

```
インデックス：1 中身：1
インデックス：2 中身：2
インデックス：3 中身：3
インデックス：4 中身：4
インデックス：5 中身：5
インデックス：6 中身：6
インデックス：7 中身：7
・・・
インデックス:9999 中身:9
```

最初はコメントアウトをしているとこを残して、malloc()とrealloc()による配列領域拡大を試してみようと思いました。実際うまくいきました。

しかし、コメントアウトをして、つまりサイズ１の領域確保のままでも結果が同じになってしまいます。

ガバガバすぎると思うんですけど、C言語の仕様なんでしょうか？

さすがに1Gぐらいまわせば何かにぶつかりそうですけど

Answer (score 7):

掲示のソースコードを `heap_overflow.c` として、gcc の `-fsanitize=address` オプションを付けてコンパイル・実行してみます。

**gcc(1)**

> **-fsanitize=address**
>
> Enable AddressSanitizer, a fast memory error detector. Memory access instructions are instrumented to detect out-of-bounds and use-after-free bugs. The option enables `-fsanitize-address-use-after-scope`. See `<https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer>` for more details. The run-time behavior can be influenced using the `ASAN_OPTIONS` environment variable. When set to `"help=1"`, the available options are shown at startup of the instrumented program. See `<https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags#run-time-flag>` for a list of supported options. The option cannot be combined with `-fsanitize=thread`.

以下の実行結果から、実際には heap buffer overflow が発生している事が判ります。

```c
$ gcc -std=gnu2x -fsanitize=address -Wall -g heap_overflow.c -o heap_overflow && ./heap_overflow

インデックス：0 中身：0
=================================================================
==118931==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000011 at pc 0x563844e782bc bp 0x7ffdd177b0b0 sp 0x7ffdd177b0a0
WRITE of size 1 at 0x602000000011 thread T0
    #0 0x563844e782bb in main heap_overflow.c:12
    #1 0x7ff235322564 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x28564)
    #2 0x563844e7816d in _start (heap_overflow+0x116d)

0x602000000011 is located 0 bytes to the right of 1-byte region [0x602000000010,0x602000000011)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7ff23559ac47 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
    #1 0x563844e7823e in main heap_overflow.c:7
    #2 0x7ff235322564 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x28564)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow heap_overflow.c:12 in main
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa[01]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==118931==ABORTING
```

Comment: 確認できました　なお、コメントアウトしない版はエラーでなくでました（freeいれわすれたので 追記しました

Answer (score 7):

> ガバガバすぎると思うんですけど、
> C言語の仕様なんでしょうか？

はい、境界を越えないように制御するのはプログラマの責任です。
その上で、C言語には既定では境界チェック機能がありません。
metropolisさんが回答されているように、追加のチェック機能を盛り込むことも可能です。
そのほかの方法として、手元のVisual C++ですとコード分析機能を使うと次のように警告が出るため、実行前に問題を把握することができます。もちろん、metropolisさんが紹介している`-fsanitize=address`も使えるため、実行時に検出することも可能です。

```
warning C6200: Index '9999' is out of valid index range '0' to '0' for non-stack buffer 'old_string'.
```

> さすがに1Gぐらいまわせば何かにぶつかりそうですけど

[`malloc`](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)に関しては、[`brk`](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man2/brk.2.html)でメモリブロックを取得し、その中を適切に切り分けたものを返す仕様となっています。そのため、`brk`で確保したサイズまではアクセスできてしまいます。それ以上のサイズにアクセスすると、アクセス違反でプロセスが停止するはずです。
現状でも`malloc`の管理領域を壊している可能性があるため、次の`malloc` / `realloc` / `free` 等が正常に動作するとは限りません。

Comment: まだ、Cが自由すぎてなじめないですね